# Employees weekly hours worked

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I am needing help with is a query to get weekly hours for employees as a total. I currently do not have any idea on how I can get this reported.

The report I have is currently only getting a report for everyone's hours, and what I would like is to be able to get a specific employees weekly total hours, I was having trouble at first because the "Shifttime" table was in minutes, not hours as a decimal so I was getting false information, not their total times.

```
SELECT     FullName, 
           DateTimeStart as StartTime, 
           DateTimeStop as FinishTime, 
           FORMAT(ShiftTime /60.0, 'n2') AS HoursWorked, 
           EL.EmployeeKey 
FROM       dbo.Employee AS E
INNER JOIN dbo.employeelog AS EL 
ON         E.EmployeeKey = EL.EmployeeKey 
ORDER BY   FullName;
```

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: What's the definition of a 'Week'? Is it starting on Sunday or Saturday or Monday? Is it fixed in your app or is based on some settings?

Comment: Hey guys, the week will go from the day of pay, so Thursday will be the start of the week, an Wednesday being the end. Sorry for not adding that in there.

Comment: What happens if DateTimeStart belongs to one week and DiteTimeStop to another?

Comment: DateTimeStart and DateTimeStop are just the times they clock on and clock off, not sure why they are as DateTimeStart and DateTimeStop and not "clock in" and "Clock Out", just how it is for the business i am working for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to provide the input date range to the query

```
SELECT     FullName, 
           --DateTimeStart as StartTime, 
           --DateTimeStop as FinishTime, 
           --FORMAT(ShiftTime /60.0, 'n2') AS HoursWorked,              
           --EL.EmployeeKey 
           SUM (DATEDIFF(minute, DateTimeStart, DateTimeStop)/60.0) AS HoursWorked
FROM       dbo.Employee AS E
INNER JOIN dbo.employeelog AS EL 
ON         E.EmployeeKey = EL.EmployeeKey 
WHERE      DateTimeStart >= '2017-03-02'
AND        DateTimeStart <  '2017-03-09'
GROUP BY   FullName
ORDER BY   FullName;
```

Comment: Works well thanks very much! If i was wanted to have it take Minutes for breaks or add bonus time given to someone, what would be the best way of querying that?

Comment: @N.Staatz, you need to provide more information to your requirement. Table Schema, sample data and expected result please